# How does methyl vinyl ketone dimerise with heating?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, carbonyl-compounds

[image]
**(A)** to **(B)** is simply reduction, tosylation followed by intramolecular reaction and removal of tosylate. However, I am not able to guess how dimerization will take place, seems similar to Rauhut–Currier reaction, but can't guess. Any hint?

Comment: TsOH does not form a tosylate. That's likely just the workup for the borohydride reduction.

Comment: My hint for you is that you can determine the which of A through D is mostly likely to be the product (B) based on several factors. Then working backwards, you can figure out what (A) is.

Comment: @Zhe Don't TsOH tosylate like TsCl? I didn't know that, if that's true. Thanks, any other way to get the answer? Any proposed mechanism?

Comment: That's kind of like how you can (sort of) alkylate stuff using alkyl chlorides RCl, but you can't alkylate stuff using alcohols ROH.

Comment: No tosic acid is not like tosyl chloride, in the same way methyl alcohol is not like methyl chloride. I have a putative mechanism, but I thought I'd let you try to figure it out for yourself first.

Comment: ... I think I'll stop jumping in here....

Comment: @orthocresol Wow. The timing is impeccable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dimer of methyl vinyl ketone (**1**) is not shown in the choices in the question. The dimer is **A** shown below. It is a "tail-to-tail" dimer. Product **B** is an intramolecular ketal as a probable mixture of epimers. Compare with [this](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo00406a009) paper.

[image]

B. P. Mundy, et al., [*J. Org. Chem.*, **1978**, *43*, 2347.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/jo00406a009)

Comment: Don't have access to the paper... And I still can't get the mechanism for dimerization....

Comment: You can usually predict Diels-Alder reactions by using ionic charges. This one is probably radical in nature. Whoever made up the structure (B) fell into this trap.